How to repress two lines from initial draw of chart, when using checkboxes to add or remove lines from a d3.js multiline chart
Edit:I updated my code and the info below on 5/14 as I'm closer to a solution.
I have a multiline chart built with d3 that allows the user to select/deselect lines using checkboxes in the legend. I want to make two of the lines deselected by default, with the user having the ability to check them and add them in if desired.
Getting the functionality of this chart working was originally addressed in another stack overflow question.
I've de-selected the checkboxes for the groups I want to exclude ("<18", "56+"). I'm running a forEach on my grouped data array before the chart is drawn, and setting d.clicked to true for the groups I want to exclude. Finally, I'm adding the the two line groups I want deselected by default to the clickedItems array. This is all working, however, when I then click on one of the deselected groups, the lines for both <18 and 56+ show up. Any idea how I can initially repress the "<18" and "56+" groups from the chart and then make it possible to add back one line at a time?


let timeW = 960,
  timeH = 450

let timeMargin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 300,
    bottom: 80,
    left: 60
  },
  timeWidth = timeW - timeMargin.left - timeMargin.right,
  timeHeight = timeH - timeMargin.top - timeMargin.bottom;

var x2 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, timeWidth]),
  y2 = d3.scaleLinear().range([timeHeight, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x2),
  yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y2);

var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x2(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y2(d.value);
  });

const seriesColors = ['#ff3300', 'royalblue', 'green', 'turquoise', 'navy']

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(seriesColors);

const parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y%m%d");

d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sprucegoose1/sample-data/main/age.csv").then(function(data) {

  var long_data = [];
  data.forEach(function(row) {
    row.date = parseDate(row.Date)
    let tableKeys = data.columns.slice(1);
    Object.keys(row).forEach(function(colname) {
      if (colname !== "date" && colname !== "Date") {
        long_data.push({
          "date": row["date"],
          "value": +row[colname],
          "bucket": colname
        });
      }
    });
  });

  data.sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date)

  let dataNest = d3.group(long_data, d => d.bucket)
  let tableKeys = data.columns.slice(1);

  console.log('data', data)
  console.log('long_data', long_data)
  console.log('dataNest', dataNest)

  let grouped_data_array = Array.from(dataNest)
    grouped_data_array.forEach(d => {
      d[0] == "<18" || d[0] == "56+" ? d.clicked = true : d.clicked = false
    })

  drawChart(long_data, grouped_data_array, tableKeys)
})

function drawChart(data, dataNest, tableKeys) {
  d3.select("#timeseries").remove()

  let timeseries = d3.select("#chart").append('svg')
    .attr('id', 'timeseries')
    .attr("width", timeWidth + timeMargin.left + timeMargin.right)
    .attr("height", timeHeight + timeMargin.top + timeMargin.bottom)

  var graph = timeseries.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + timeMargin.left + ',' + timeMargin.top + ')');

  var focus = timeseries.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + timeMargin.left + "," + timeMargin.top + ")");

  x2.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.date;
  }));
  y2.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.value;
  })]);

  focus
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(dataNest)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr('class', d => 'groups a' + d[0].replaceAll("+", "").replaceAll("<", "").replaceAll(" ", "_"))
    .attr("d", d => {
      // d.line = this;
      if (d.clicked == false) {
        return line(d[1])
      }
    })
    .style("stroke", d => color(d[0]))
    .style("stroke-width", 1)
    .style('fill', 'none')
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")

  focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + timeHeight + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(yAxis);

  var gXAxis = focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + timeHeight + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  var gYAxis = focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(yAxis);

  let clickedItems = ["<18", "56+"]

  var legend = timeseries.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'legend')
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (timeW - timeMargin.right + 10) + "," + timeMargin.top + ")")

  var legendGroups = legend
    .selectAll(".legendGroup")
    .data(dataNest, d => d[0])

  var enterGroups = legendGroups
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", d => "legendGroup " + d[0].replaceAll(" ", "_").replace("<", ""))
    .on("click", function(event, d) {
      console.log('d', d)

      d.clicked = !d.clicked;

      // toggle the rectangle's fill
      d3.select('rect.a' + d[0].replaceAll(" ", "_").replace("+", "").replace("<", "")).attr("fill", d.clicked ? "transparent" : d => color(d[0]));

      // hide/show the associated line
      d3.select("path.a" + d[0].replaceAll(" ", "_").replace("+", "").replace("<", "")).style("display", d.clicked ? "none" : "block");

      // hide/show the associated table row
      d3.select(".row.a" + d[0].replaceAll(" ", "_").replace("+", "").replace("<", "")).style("display", d.clicked ? "none" : "block");

      let i = d3.selectAll(".legend-rect").nodes().indexOf(this);
      d3.selectAll(".group" + i).style("display", d.clicked ? "none" : "block");

      // Logic for all empty:
      // keep track of unchecked boxes (also used in rescaling below):
      d.clicked ? clickedItems.push(d[0]) : clickedItems.splice(clickedItems.indexOf(d[0]), 1);

      // If all are empty:
      // if (clickedItems.length == tableKeys.length) {
      //     d3.selectAll(".legend-rect")
      //         .attr("fill", d => color(d[0]))
      //         .each(d => d.clicked = false);
      //     d3.selectAll(".groups")
      //         .style("display", "");
      //     clickedItems = [];
      // }

      // re-scale
      x2.domain(d3.extent(data.filter(d => clickedItems.indexOf(d.bucket) == -1), function(d) {
        return d.date;
      }));
      y2.domain([0, d3.max(data.filter(d => clickedItems.indexOf(d.bucket) == -1), function(dd) {
        return dd.value;
      })]);

      gYAxis.call(yAxis)
      gXAxis.call(xAxis)

      focus.selectAll("path.groups")
        .transition() // May want to use clip area for the line here.
        .attr("d", d => {
          return line(d[1]);
        })
      console.log('clicked items', clickedItems)

    })

  legendGroups
    .exit()
    .remove();

  enterGroups
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("height", 10)
    .attr("fill", d => color(d[0]))
    .attr("stroke", d => color(d[0]))
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr('stroke-opacity', 1)
    .attr("x", 30)
    .attr("y", (d, i) => i * 20)
    .attr("class", d => "a" + d[0].replace("+", "").replace("<", "") + ' legend-rect')

  enterGroups
    .append("text")
    .attr('class', 'legend-text')
    .text(d => d[0])
    .attr("x", 45)
    .attr("y", (d, i) => 10 + i * 20)

  enterGroups
    .append("foreignObject")
    .attr("x", 15)
    .attr("y", (d, i) => i * 19)
    .attr("width", 12)
    .attr("height", 14)
    .attr("id", (d, i) => 'a' + i)
    .append("xhtml:tree")
    .html(d => d[0] == "56+" || d[0] == "<18" ? "<input type='checkbox' class='check'>" : "<input type='checkbox' checked class='check'>")
    .attr('class', 'checkcontainer')

};
#chart {
  height: 450px;
  width: 760px;
}

.check {
  width: 11px;
  height: 12px;
  filter: grayscale(1);
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: -1px !important;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>




I would rework this chart completely. Make a function to setup an initial state of the chart. Separate out the the parts that need to rerender. Use filter keyword to filter the data lines depending on the checkbox state.
